# Find Unique count on field using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to determine the Distinct count for a particular field in a collection of objects.

```
    private static RemittanceCenterBatchSummaryListModel SummarizeFields(RemittanceCenterSummaryListModel remittanceCenterSummaryListModel)
    {
        var result = remittanceCenterSummaryListModel.RemittanceBatchSummaryRecord.GroupBy(x => new{x.FileId, x.SourceFileName, x.BatchCode, x.BatchType})
            .Select(x => new RemittanceCenterBatchSummarizedModel()
            {
                FileId = x.Key.FileId,
                SourceFileName = x.Key.SourceFileName,
                BatchCode = x.Key.BatchCode,
                BatchType = x.Key.BatchType,
                DetailRecordCountAdc = x.Count(y => y.BillingSystemCode == BillingSystemCode.Adc),
                DetailRecordCountNotAdc = x.Count(y => y.BillingSystemCode == BillingSystemCode.Exd),
                AmountAdc = x.Where(y => y.BillingSystemCode == BillingSystemCode.Adc).Sum(y => y.PaymentAmount),
                AmountNotAdc = x.Where(y => y.BillingSystemCode == BillingSystemCode.Exd).Sum(y => y.PaymentAmount),
                UniqueFileCount = x.Select(y => x.Key.FileId).Distinct().Count()
            });

        return CreateSummaryListModel(result);
    }
```

Input entities:

```
    public class RemittanceCenterSummaryListModel
{

    public RemittanceCenterSummaryListModel()
    {
        this.RemittanceBatchSummaryRecord = new List<RemittanceBatchProcessingModel>();
    }

    public List<RemittanceBatchProcessingModel> RemittanceBatchSummaryRecord { get; private set; }
}

 public class RemittanceCenterBatchSummarizedModel
{
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string SourceFileName { get; set; }
    public string BatchCode { get; set; }
    public string BatchType { get; set; }
    public int DetailRecordCountAdc { get; set; }
    public int DetailRecordCountNotAdc { get; set; }
    public int DetailRecordCountTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountAdc { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountNotAdc { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountTotal { get; set; }
    public BillingSystemCode BillingSystemCode { get; set; }
    public int UniqueFileCount { get; set; }
}

    private static RemittanceCenterBatchSummaryListModel CreateSummaryListModel(IEnumerable<RemittanceCenterBatchSummarizedModel> summaryModels)
    {
        var summaryModelList = new RemittanceCenterBatchSummaryListModel();

        foreach (var summaryRec in summaryModels)
        {
            var summaryModel = new RemittanceCenterBatchSummarizedModel
            {
                FileId = summaryRec.FileId,
                SourceFileName = summaryRec.SourceFileName,
                BatchCode = summaryRec.BatchCode,
                BatchType = summaryRec.BatchType,
                DetailRecordCountAdc = summaryRec.DetailRecordCountAdc,
                DetailRecordCountNotAdc = summaryRec.DetailRecordCountNotAdc,
                AmountAdc = summaryRec.AmountAdc,
                AmountNotAdc = summaryRec.AmountNotAdc,
                UniqueFileCount = summaryRec.UniqueFileCount
            };

            summaryModelList.RemittanceBatchSummary.Add(summaryModel);
        }

        return summaryModelList;
    }
```

Example input records:

Record1:

```
   FileId: '123'
   SourceFileName: 'test.file.txt'
   BatchCode: 'aaa'
   BatchType: 'scanned'
   PaymentAmount: '50.00'
   BillingSystemCode: 'Adc'
```

Record1:

```
   FileId: '1234'
   SourceFileName: 'test.file2.txt'
   BatchCode: 'aab'
   BatchType: 'scanned'
   PaymentAmount: '52.00'
   BillingSystemCode: 'Adc'
```

ActualOuput for UniqueFileCount Field:

```
    UniqueFileCount = 1
```

ExpectedOutput results for UniqueFileCount Field:

```
    UniqueFileCount = 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The samples you added have different FileIds so the count returned would be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the distinct count of `FileId` for the entire collection and not just for each group, which will always be 1 since `FileId` is one of the fields you group on.  If that is the case then you can just calculate that count first

```
int distinctFileIds = remittanceCenterSummaryListModel.RemittanceBatchSummaryRecor‌​d
    .Select(x => x.FileId)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

Then use that in your Linq query

```
UniqueFileCount = distinctFileIds
```